# Strange issue with Laravel 5.4 app.js -> register and login content not displayed on live server version

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I just rolled out a fresh laravel 5.4 installation with basic authentication. Nothing more. In local development everything works as expected. In the production version I'm not able to see the content of the pages login, register and password reset.

If I disable JavaScript everything is displayed. Also by renaming the first

`<div id="app">` to `<div id="somethingElse">` it's getting displayed.

Here's the link to the live version:

[glembo.de/login](https://www.glembo.de/login)

I don't know what is wrong with the application. Here are all the steps I've done until deployment:

1. laravel new app
2. php artisan make:auth
3. uploaded the project to live server
4. edited .env file with environment specific data
5. php artisan migrate

Edit: All the code is out of the box from the laravel installer.

Here is the resources/assets/js/app.js

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Here is the resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

require('bootstrap-sass');

/**
 * Vue is a modern JavaScript library for building interactive web interfaces
 * using reactive data binding and reusable components. Vue's API is clean
 * and simple, leaving you to focus on building your next great project.
 */

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

// import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

// window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

// window.Echo = new Echo({
//     broadcaster: 'pusher',
//     key: 'your-pusher-key'
// });
```

Comment: There is an error in console: **Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src * 'unsafe-inline'”). Source: call to eval() or related function blocked by CSP.**

Comment: @MayankPandeyz my console doesn't show any error or warning. :-(

Comment: @MayankPandeyz I didn't get an error either.

op: can you post your basic app.js and bootstrap.js scripts please?

Comment: I am using Firefox and the html content are visible for a friction of second and then disappear the above error showing in the console

Comment: @dops added the code

Comment: @glembo only just got that message, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for this "error". It was caused by my own directive in the apache header settings. I placed a CSP directive:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src * 'unsafe-inline'"
```

wich caused the problem. Now everything works. Thanks to @MayankPandeyz for the detected error message with firefox. Unfortunately chrome and safari didn't throw an error into the console.